# Extract data between delimiters from a Shell Script variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have this shell script variable, **var**. It keeps 3 entries separated by *new line*. From this variable **var**, I want to extract ***2***, and ***0.078688***. Just these two numbers.

```
var="USER_ID=2
     # 0.078688
     Suhas"
```

These are the code I tried:

```
echo "$var" | grep -o -P '(?<=\=).*(?=\n)' # For extracting 2

echo "$var" | awk -v FS="(# |\n)" '{print $2}' # For extracting 0.078688
```

None of the above working. What is the problem here? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$var" |grep -oP 'USER_ID=\K.*'
2
echo "$var" |grep -oP '# \K.*'
0.078688
```

Your solution is near to perfect, you need to chance `\n` to `$` which represent end of line.

```
echo "$var"  |awk -F'# ' '/#/{print $2}'
0.078688
echo "$var"  |awk -F'=' '/USER_ID/{print $2}'
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `tr` alone for retaining the numerical digits, the dot (`.`) and the white-space and remove everything else.

```
tr -cd '0-9. ' <<<"$var"
2      0.078688
```

From the `man` page, of `tr` for usage of `-c`, `-d` flags,

> tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]
>
> -c, -C, --complement
>                 use the complement of SET1
>
> -d, --delete
>                 delete characters in SET1, do not translate

To store it in variables,

```
IFS=' ' read -r var1 var2 < <(tr -cd '0-9. ' <<<"$var")
printf "%s\n" "$var1"
2
printf "%s\n" "$var2"
2
0.078688
```

Or in an array as

```
IFS=' ' read -ra numArray < <(tr -cd '0-9. ' <<<"$var")
printf "%s\n" "${numArray[@]}"
2
0.078688
```

Note:- The `-cd` flags in `tr` are `POSIX` compliant and will work on any systems that has `tr` installed.

Comment: `++` because is witty! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure bash using a regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="USER_ID=2
 # 0.078688
 Suhas"

[[ ${var} =~ =([0-9]+).*#[[:space:]]([0-9\.]+) ]] && result1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && result2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "${result1}"
echo "${result2}"
```

Comment: `++` for not using _other-tools_ and just 'shell` utilities.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

First value:

```
echo "$var" | grep 'USER_ID' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'
```

Second value:

```
echo "$var" | grep '#' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: youa re taking incorrect input data, do `echo "$var"` to get the correct data. its multi-line data.

Comment: Appreciate your attempt. But this will not work since OP has a new line character between the words. And your example will work only if OP doesn't quote which will contradict the question.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio: When you say `I didn't quote "var" intentionally`, that is incorrect, it is not right to work on unquoted variables in `bash` which leads to a worrying aspect called [`Word Splitting`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). quoting it actually preserves the string _as-is_ and it is not a privilege to work on unquoted stuff!

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio: Appreciate your attempt though! Cheers!

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio: This will break if the line `Suhas` is swapped with the first line. Maybe think of a way to make it generic to work on any order of lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the format of data as your sample

```
# For extracting 2
echo "$var" | sed -e '/.*=/!d' -e 's///'
echo "$var" | awk -F '=' 'NR==1{ print $2}'

# For extracting 0.078688
echo "$var" | sed -e '/.*#[[:blank:]]*/!d' -e 's///' 
echo "$var" | awk -F '#' 'NR==2{ print $2}'
```